# Mysql returning empty set

Tags: mysql

```
select 
    ag.name, aa.name, al.object_id, u.name, al.performed_by, al.datetime, 
    aa1.name, et.name, ald.name, ald.value
from 
    'db'.'table1' al, 'db'.'table2' ald, 'db'.'table3' ag, 
    'db'.'table4' aa, 'db'.'table5' aa1, 'db'.'table6' et, 
    'db'.'table7' u
where 
    al.id = ald.log_id 
    and al.datetime > DATE_SUB(sysdate(). INTERVAL 90 DAY) 
    and al.group_id = ag.id 
    and ag.name = 'User' 
    and al.action_id = aa1.id 
    and al.object_id = u.user_id 
    and ald.type_id = et.id;
```

The above query returns empty set in mysql but the data is present . How to troubleshoot it?

Please help...
Thanks in Advance....

Comment: First recommendation: Use `JOIN`s instead of `WHERE` conditions; it makes your query clearer and easier to debug.

Comment: there is no relation with table4 aa ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dont use single quotes around table database , columns name use instead backticks .

try this:

```
     from 
`db`.`table1` al, `db`.`table2` ald, `db`.`table3` ag, 
`db`.`table4` aa, `db`.`table5` aa1, `db`.`table6` et, 
`db`.`table7` u
```

try this with joins

```
    select 
ag.name, aa.name, al.object_id, u.name, al.performed_by, al.datetime, 
aa1.name, et.name, ald.name, ald.value
from 
`db`.`table1` al  
Inner join `db`.`table2` ald On al.id = ald.log_id 
Inner join  `db`.`table3` ag On  al.group_id = ag.id
Inner join  `db`.`table4` aa On  """""the condition of relation with this table""""
Inner join  `db`.`table5` aa1 On al.action_id = aa1.id
Inner join  `db`.`table6` et On  ald.type_id = et.id
Inner join `db`.`table7` u  On al.object_id = u.user_id 
where 
  al.datetime > DATE_SUB(sysdate(), INTERVAL 90 DAY) 
  and ag.name = 'User'
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply,
I tried with backticks ,then also it is returning empty set again 
Below are the reference which i have ried.

from 
    `db`.`table1` al, `db`.`table2` ald, `db`.`table3` ag, 
    `db`.`table4` aa, `db`.`table5` aa1, `db`.`table6` et, 
    `db`.`table7` u

Above Returns empty.

from 
    `db`.`table1` `al`, `db`.`table2` `ald`, `db`.`table3` `ag`, 
    `db`.`table4` `aa`, `db`.`table5` `aa1`, `db`.`table6` `et`, 
    `db`.`table7` `u`
where
    ****    and ag.name = 'User'   ****
Above returns error as 
Unknown column 'User" in 'where clause'

Comment: Thank you again.
Appreciate your help.
I tried a lot of ways including joins and on , is returning empty set.

Comment: look my `DATE_SUB(sysdate(), INTERVAL 90 DAY)` its with comma not point as you done in your query

Comment: this can be with your where clause for sure , try this `and ag.name = 'user'` . note the small u not U .

Comment: @user2668829 you welcome ! :). make sure to accept the answer as solved,to help others.